# Select second row with placeholder

Tags: mysql, database

I want to select a second row from "my_table", by only knowing "my_table_id". The second row id is "copy_id". Is there a way to do it in one SELECT statement? I could easily do it in two selects, but want to avoid that.

```
my_table
    copy_id | my_table_id
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: copy_id is a my_table_id from the same table

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly want, but the following should do it.

```
SELECT a.copy_id
  FROM my_table a
 WHERE a.my_table_id = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT b.my_table_id AS copy_id
  FROM my_table b
 WHERE b.my_table_id = ?
```

Comment: I think this would make it. But i want it in one Select string since it have many Joins